# Problem Deploying Wicket/JPA (EclipseLink) App to Glassfish

Tags: deployment, jpa, glassfish, wicket, eclipselink

I have a small Wicket app that I can deploy to Glassfish v3 without any problems.  I also have a JAX-RS webservice that includes a jar file that contains JPA entity beans and stateless service beans that deploys successfully.  However, when I try to deploy a different Wicket application that makes use of the same entity/service jar, I get this
exception:

```
SEVERE: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer load method

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load EJB module. DeploymentContext does not contain any EJB  Check archive to ensure correct packaging for C:\Program Files\glassfishv3\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\MyApp

  at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:133)
  at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:63)
  at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:175)
<snip>
```

The same dependent jar files are included in both the Wicket and web service wars.

Does anyone know if this a Wicket/JPA/Glassfish issue or something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer in this post: [Deploy war through netbeans onto glassfish v3 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617191/deploy-war-through-netbeans-onto-glassfish-v3-beta)

I needed to change the web.xml version to 2.5

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">
```

Comment: I created the project using the wicket-archetype-quickstart which sets it to:  
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">