# Netbeans, Glassfish deployment problem

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans, glassfish, ejb

I am developing a web project using Netbeans 6.9.1 and Glassfish 3.0.1.

Everything was fine until I refector a sesion bean by renaming it from “outboxSession” to “OutboxSession”. Now the project cannot be deployed. I have tried many thinks like restarting Glassfish, restarting Netbeans, restarting my PC itself, deleting the built folder in my project and clean and build my project. Nothing works. Finally I deleted the “OutboxSession” and tried, but no success.

My project can be built without errors, but when try to deploy NoClassFound error is thrown (by Glassfish). Please advice me to overcome this issue.

Bellow is the stack trace:

```
WARNING: Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/myproject/backing/pages/myaccount/outbox/outboxSession (wrong name: com/myproject/backing/pages/myaccount/outbox/OutboxSession)
SEVERE: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer load method
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load EJB module.  DeploymentContext does not contain any EJB  Check archive to ensure correct packaging for D:\Netbeans\myproject\build\web
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:63)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:175)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:216)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:338)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

SEVERE: Exception while loading the app
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load EJB module.  DeploymentContext does not contain any EJB  Check archive to ensure correct packaging for D:\Netbeans\myproject\build\web
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:63)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:175)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:216)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:338)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
```

Comment: can you post whole stack trace ?

Comment: I have posted the stack trace bellow

Comment: You should post your stacktrace by editting your question. btw check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617191/deploy-war-through-netbeans-onto-glassfish-v3-beta

Comment: Now the stack trace is with my initial post

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the session bean binding has not been updated in the sources.  I would not expect this as Netbeans is quite a mature product.

If not, you might have hit a "Windows is case-insensitive, Java is case-sensitive" issue, where a resource is found even if was with the old spelling.

Refactor it to something with a different spelling, and try again.

Comment: I have searched in the project using Netbeans "search in the project" feature and confirm that the specified resources are not used in my project now. (project can be built without errors)

Answer (score 0):

I think your EJB descriptor hasn't been updated during refactoring. The easiest way to fix this even if you don't know anything about EJB descriptor files would be searching your project directory for files that contain string "OutboxSession" case sensitive and fix this manually in any files that still has this name.